# How is the linux graphics stack organised?

Tags: linux, graphics

How is the linux graphics stack organised? Can anyone explain about this?
I'm trying to understand the graphics stack in linux.

Comment: Please add some details which part you want to understand - one could write books about the graphics stack.

Comment: about the applications interaction with graphics stack and how they access the graphics hardware through linux kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First hit when searching in Google for "the linux graphics stack":

http://blog.mecheye.net/2012/06/the-linux-graphics-stack

Comment: No, damnit, first one is this page now!!